# Codeigniter XML Array explode php

Tags: php, xml, arrays, codeigniter, explode

I have a controller merchant_import and creating an array from xml

```
public function merchant_import_kgb(){
        if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('admin/login');
        }

        $data['pageTitle'] = 'Merchant Admin';
        $data['error_warning'] = '';
        $data['success'] = '';

        $xmlfile= base_url().'feeds/kgb.xml';  
        $xmlRaw = file_get_contents($xmlfile);  

        $this->load->library('xml');  
        $xmlData = $this->xml->xml_parse($xmlRaw);  

        ?><pre><?php var_dump($xmlData); ?></pre><?php

        foreach($xmlData['merchant']['prod'] as $product){
            list($titleNew, $partner, $city) = explode(" - ", $product['text']['name']);

            $deal[] = array(
                'id' => $product['pId'],
                'dealTitle' => $titleNew,
                'price' => $product['price']['buynow'],
                'image' => $product['uri']['mThumb'],
                'buyLink' => $product['uri']['awTrack'],
                'endDate' => $product['valTo'],
                'partner' => $partner,
                'city' => $city,
                'description' => $product['text']['desc'],
                'RRP' => $product['price']['rrp'],
                'category' => $product['cat']['mCat'],
                'discount' => $this->getDiscount($product['price']['buynow'], $product['price']['rrp'])
            );
        }

        ?><pre><?php var_dump($deal);?></pre><?php
    }
```

The problem I am having is that the $parts[2] is giving an undefined offset with some and others its formating nicely. I have checked the xml and all titles are Title - Partner - City - kgbdeals. When formatting array though the explode() isn't working correctly. Any ideas?

Edit - tried using preg_split(), split(), and explode all with near enough same result, totally lost :(

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 3 different functions you could:

```
list($titleNew, $partner, $city) = split("[-]", $title);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: so would this go in the foreach above the deals array and then the deals array dealtitle=>$title new ?

Comment: just tried see amended code above still giving undefined offset in some deals :( lol

Answer (score 0):

remove the spaces around hyphen and then check:

```
$parts = explode("-", $title);
```

Comment: tried removing spaces doesn't help, thanks for your time tho mate :)